# dojo: aspect.after is not working

Tags: dojo

Guys have been trying since an hour. But unable to figure out that why the aspect.after/before is not being called. This is my code.

```
 require([ "dojo/aspect", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(
    aspect, on, registry, dom) {

   var callback = function() {
    alert("called by click");
     };
   var callback2 = function() {
    alert("called by click 2");
         };
   var my = {
    clicking : on(dom.byId("alertButton"), "click", callback)
     };

    aspect.after(my, "clicking", callback2);

 });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you confusing the usage.

`aspect.after` or `aspect.before`, it is execute additional functions base on the methods. Not the action.

example:

`aspect.after(my, "clicking", callback2);`

Anywhere which calling `my.clicking()` it will run `callback2`.

**NOT** for execute additional function when running `on(dom.byId("alertButton"), "click", callback)`.

My English is not good, simple to explain:

```
function a(){
    alert();
}

my.clicking = function(){ a(); };
aspect.after(my, "clicking", callback2);

//equals to
my.clicking = function(){ a(); callback2(); };

//but not equals to
function a(){
    alert();
    callback2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could like to base on an action to add additional function, you could try this:

```
<input type="button" id="alertButton" value="click me" />
<input type="text" id="textboxMessage" value="x" />
<script>
    dojo.require("dojo.aspect");
    dojo.require("dojo.on");
    dojo.require("dojo.dom");

    var handler = {};
    handler.alertClick = function(){ console.log('first callback'); };
    handler.msgBoxChange = function(){ console.log('a textbox value changed'); };
    handler.serverListChg = function(){ console.log('dropdown menu selected'); };
    handler.additional = function(){ console.log('Additional callback'); };

    dojo.aspect.after(handler, "alertClick", handler.additional, true);

    dojo.on(dojo.byId('alertButton'), "click", handler.alertClick);
    dojo.on(dojo.byId('textboxMessage'), "change", handler.msgBoxChange);
</script>
```

In the example, the action `handler.additional` will be appended after `handler.alertClick`